# Generate a tag list in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a long list of article texts in ***ArticleList*** (1000+ items, with 50+ words each)

And I have a list of tags in ***TagList*** (100 items, 1 word each)

I want to return a list of matching tags (from ***TagList***) for each word in ***ArticleList***.

e.g.

***ArticleList*** = {"the big yellow teapot"; "the small white cup"; "the medium brown pan"; "grey flask"}

***TagList*** = {"the", "yellow", "teapot", "white", "pan"}

***ResultsList*** = {"the, yellow, teapot"; "the, white"; "the, pan"; ""}

So basically any words not in ***TagList*** are removed from ***ArticleList*** and the ***ResultsList*** is left in the same order as original ***ArticleList***.

NB: ***ArticleList*** is clean and comprises space separated words and case is not important.

I think I got someway towards a solution by splitting ***ArticleList*** into a List of Lists on the space delimiter, but I could not figure how to manipulate the Nested Lists from that point.  Tried using ***List.Transform(ListofLists, each List.Intersect({_,TagList}){0}?)***, but it returns a single list instead of keeping the List of Lists integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have a list called ArticleList, created with this M code:

```
let
    Source = {"the big yellow teapot", "the small white cup", "the medium brown pan", "grey flask"}
in
    Source
```

[image]

And a list called TagList, created with this M code:

```
let
    Source = {"the", "yellow", "teapot", "white", "pan"}
in
    Source
```

[image]

Then I can use this M code to do what you want:

```
let
    Source = List.Transform(List.Transform(ArticleList, each Text.Split(_," ")), each List.Intersect({_,TagList})),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {"Column1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I did not appreciate that the each statements cold be nested like that.